# Nifi output null values for EvaluateJson or AttributesToJson

Tags: json, apache-nifi

So when I parse a file with EvaluateJSON the JSON looks like this:

```
{ "TEST_DATE": "", "T_DATE": "" }
```

When I do EvaluateJSON ($.TEST_DATE) to "test-date" on attributes... I get:

```
test-date: ""
```

Then when I do AttributesToJSON (flowfile-content destination) I get:

```
{ "test-date": "", "t-date": "" }
```

HOWEVER... I want it to be:

```
{ "test-date": null, "t-date": null }
```

I have tried every possible option. There is no way aside from "ReplaceText"-style dangerous regex to put NULL into the JSON.

Any updateAttribute fails to put "null" into it. I tried "replaceEmpty(null)", replaceEmpty("null") (which puts a string "null" instead). I tried "replaceEmpty(literal("null")) doesn't work.

It's like Nifi doesn't recognize null.

Comment: seems you want the same:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593240/delete-empty-attributes-in-nifi

Comment: Yes so I think my solution is to use a custom NAR processor that does "Delete Empty Attributes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DExter,

You can replace the double quotes("") by null value in ReplaceText processor.

Afterwards you get below value.

```
{ "test-date": "", "t-date": "" }
```

Use ReplaceText processor to be search for empty double quotes and replace it with null.

```
search value:""
Replacement value:null
```

For your reference check this https://regexr.com/3kctp.

It will end like your required result;

```
{ "test-date": null, "t-date": null }
```

Please let me know, if you face any issues.

Comment: I felt this was not such a great way to do this, but if we are gonna replace all  "" anyway, then it makes perfect sense to just do it this way instead of a custom nar. The custom nar or script execute might work for only SOME that need to be replaced.

Comment: I do the same as you suggested and for values like above with null, in the next step, i use the expression language like ${ATTR_NAME:isNull()} on UpdateAttribute processor. But it doesn't detect the value as null, rather considers it as empty string set. do you know why? Hence the attribute always returns/set to false although the value is null. I see the formatted view as well. what is missing or what am i doing wrong for checking/using isNull() to those null replaced values in json?