# Apache NiFi. Change mulpiple attributes by one rule

Tags: apache-nifi

After ConverJSONToSQL processor complete, I have about 60 attributes. Some of them may be empty.
How can I set them a same value "no" (via UpdateAttribute proc) by one rule?

I can do this with UpdateAttribute -> Advanced -> made ~60 rules for each attribute:

```
${sql.args.1.value:isNull()} -> Actions:...,
${sql.args.2.value:isNull()} -> Actions:...,
...
${sql.args.60.value:isNull()} -> Actions:...
```

But I think it is a wrong way...

Comment: so, you want to have the same value for 60 parameters of UpdateAttribute?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [ExecuteScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html)  to get all attributes that are empty, and replace with whatever value you like. See these [cookbooks](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922) for more detail on how to use ExecuteScript.

@daggett provided a similar answer that you could adapt here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48611176/3955972